# Incorrect title with link in google crawler

Tags: seo, web-crawler, google-crawlers

Recently I found a problem in my website, when I search a movie name in my site I found two link with the same title.
Second search result has following problems:

- The link refers to "shahrzad" movie
- You find "mad max" movie name in the url
- You find "abad o yek rooz" movie name in the title

These data are about three different pages. I got confused what's going on here.
Recently I found some other link like this in google search 
[Wrong URL that google show](http://www.salamcinama.ir/movie/343/%D9%85%DA%A9%D8%B3-%D8%AF%DB%8C%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%87-%D8%AC%D8%A7%D8%AF%D9%87-%D8%AE%D8%B4%D9%85)
[Correct URL that google show](http://www.salamcinama.ir/movie/376/%D8%A7%D8%A8%D8%AF-%D9%88-%DB%8C%DA%A9-%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%B2)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check head of your html page, maybe you use `canonical` tag in a wrong way, for example if you set another url to `href` attribute, you will have some serious SEO problem:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="<some_url>" />
```

For more information read [this link](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en).